# Random type object in Java is giving me always the same number

Tags: java, random

How to get different random number every time in Java:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Guess_tutorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random random = new Random(100);
        int rand_num = random.nextInt(100);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your number: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        while (n != rand_num) {

            if (n > rand_num) {
                System.out.println("Too high!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Too low!");
            }

            n = sc.nextInt();
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("That's right!");
    }
}
```

It's always 15. What am I doint wrong? Trying to learn Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing a constant seed to the `Random` constructor. Don't do that. And it will default to a seed derived from the time. Change

```
Random random = new Random(100);
```

to

```
Random random = new Random();
```